# Updating OR Deleting a line from SQL Database in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I read a bunch of posts about this, couldn't make it work here though (apologies in advance)

(Python version 3.7.0)
I have a SQLite3 database:

`cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE everyone(NAME text primary key, ROLE text, SECTION text, USED text)""")`

The data looks like this in the table:

[image]

I'm pulling x amount of names at random, where Role = FLM

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
for i in range(3):
    names = secure_random.choice(results)
    print(f'{names}')
```

This gives me the names I want, and when I print I see:

('Joe Blow 12345',)

I now want to delete Joe Blow from the list completely, OR enter something in the "Used" field (which is just a work around because I couldn't seem to delete)

Here's my code containing the selection of people, and my attempt to update:

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
for i in range(3):
    names = secure_random.choice(results)
    print(f'{names}')
    #try:
        #cursor.execute(f'''UPDATE everyone SET USED = "Y" WHERE NAME = {names} ''')
    #except:
        #print('Something went wrong updating names in the database.')
    try:
        execute('''UPDATE everyone SET USED = ? WHERE NAME = ?''', (used_var, names))
    except:
        print('Something went wrong updating names in the database.')
        break
```

No matter how I try this, I can't get it right.

For this:
`cursor.execute('''UPDATE everyone SET USED = ? WHERE NAME = ?''', (used_var, names))`

I get "InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type."

For this:
`cursor.execute(f'''UPDATE everyone SET USED = "Y" WHERE NAME = {names} ''')`

I get "OperationalError: near ")": syntax error"

I didn't think to record all of the different ways I've tried, I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: What is `used_var`?

Answer (score 0):

Quotations around my f-string variable in the update line fixed this right up for me